# useDapp useContractFunction state not updating

Tags: transactions, dapps, react, state

In React i am using useDapp hook **useContractFunction** to call a contract function, it returns a **send** function (works perfectly), and a **state** object that represents current state of a transaction, before sending transaction the state is **None**, but when sending the transaction and until the success, it never updates . I don't knwo where is the problem . I am using version : **1.2.2**

**My hook file :**

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { Contract } from '@ethersproject/contracts';
import PaidPromotion from "./../chain-info/contracts/PaidPromotion.json";
import { useContractFunction } from "@usedapp/core";


const paidPromotionAddress = "0x6f0424cB89Cc3eCe46D2FA1dcC7fd1907357ED47"
const { abi } = PaidPromotion
const paidPromotionInterface = new ethers.utils.Interface(abi)
const paidPromotionContract = new Contract(paidPromotionAddress, paidPromotionInterface)


export const useEndCollaboration = () => {


    const { state, send } = useContractFunction(paidPromotionContract, "endCollab", {});
   

 return { state, send };
```

}

**React component:**

```
function EndCollaboration() {

    const [id, setId] = useState(null)

    function handleInputChange(event) {
        setId(event.target.value);
    }

    const { state, send } = useEndCollaboration();

    const { status } = state

    function handleEndCollaboration(event) {
        send(id);
        event.currentTarget.disabled = true;

        event.preventDefault();

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(state)
    }, [state])

    return (
        <div >
           <h1>Status:{status}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default EndCollaboration;
```